# Magento 2: How to change the default country in the "Estimate shipping" block in cart?

Tags: magento2, custom, design

I've set my default country (Spain) in admin, also set it to be the only destination country available for shipping, however in the cart the default country is United States. How can I change it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`General -> Country Options -> Allow Countries` was bugged until 2.1.

Instead to have a default country (Spain) in cart shipping quotes you have to set it in

`Tax -> Default Tax Destination Calculation -> Default Country`.

I continue to don't understand what `General -> Country Options -> Default Country` means if it is near to `Allow Countries` that is referrred to shipping quotes.

**It is struggled.**

Comment: Got same problem in 2.1 and the config mentioned here was hidden in `Stores / Configuration / Sales / Tax / Default Country` (I'm using Italian locale, so labels in other versions might be slightly different).

Comment: i was looking for solution to change default country in checkout page , and this solved my problems, thanks :)

Comment: 2.3.7, still the same problem. Insane :)

Answer (score 1):

In the admin got to

```
Store -> Configuration -> General -> General
```

In there you can set the default country and the allowed country.

Comment: I've already done that, doesn't work.

Comment: hello developers  I am  struggling for  **How can customize tax rules for different stores for common country** https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303861/magento-2-3-x-how-can-customise-tax-rules-for-different-stores-for-common-count